# Size of watermark differs with phones

Tags: android

I want to add watermark to my app. The screen is divided into 4 rectangle,size of each are ScreenWidth * 1/4ScreenHeight.And each rectangle contains two watermarks.The code is posted below:

```
final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    ScreenInitControl screenInitControl = new ScreenInitControl(getActivity());
    int screenWidth = screenInitControl.getScreenWidth();
    int screenHeight = screenInitControl.getScreenHeight();
    int bitmapWidth = screenWidth;
    int bitmapHeight = screenHeight / 4;
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setHasAlpha(true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

    // init paint
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    paint.setAlpha(100);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    paint.setTextSize(50);

    // the water mark text
    String watermarkText = Config.getIns().getName();

    // draw the first watermark in a row
    int x = 30;
    int y = bitmapHeight / 2;
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(x, y);
    path.lineTo(bitmapWidth / 2, 30);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(watermarkText, path, 0, 30, paint);

    // draw the second watermark in a row
    Path path1 = new Path();
    x = bitmapWidth / 2 + 30;
    y = bitmapHeight / 2;
    path1.moveTo(x, y);
    path1.lineTo(bitmapWidth, 30);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(watermarkText, path1, 0, 30, paint);

    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
    bitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

    // add the watermark onto background
    final View watermarkView = new View(getActivity());
    watermarkView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, screenHeight));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        watermarkView.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
    } else {
        watermarkView.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
    }
    rootView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            rootView.addView(watermarkView);
        }
    }, 50);
```

The code work fine in Samsung galaxy A5. But when I install the app on OPPO R11S, the wartermark comes to be 1/3 size of that in Samsung.Do I ignore something?
[image: Samsung screenshot]

[image: OPPO screenshot]

Comment: probably your `ScreenInitControl` is working incorrectly.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have checked and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I find it that `BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap)` is deprecated. I use `BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap)` instead and the problem is solved.